# Set multiple Threshold + Log4Net Appender

Tags: c#, log4net

I want to log debugging, information and warnings into an one appender and errors and fatal errors to another appender.

for that I have created two custom appender using below code

```
internal class CustomAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Append
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="loggingEvent">The loggingEvent</param>
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
    }
}
```

and I have set Threshold using below code

```
var customAppender = new CustomAppender
{
    Threshold = Level.All 
};
customAppender.ActivateOptions();
```

How can I set the multiple Threshold values without using config file.

Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

Appender will log messages, whose level is equal or above the specified threshold. So for "Warn" level, it will log "Warn", "Error" and "Fatal".

Comment: Here I am expecting my specific custom appender log the Error only other Appender log the Warn only. How can I implement this scenario.